# I am searching for a prototyping software to design my app (Android)

Tags: android, mobile, prototyping

I am searching for a software where it is possible to prototype your mobile app, in my case an Android App. It should be a very light software where i can build up my views and pages like Activities to have a nice overview for my customers... I know there is a software called Sketch but it is as far as i know only for OS Systems, and i work with Linux/Ubuntu. Maybe somebody knows any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Google acquired Pixate (http://www.pixate.com) 4 days ago and it's now free for use (the paid plan is for sync your projects on the cloud). The software is very powerfull but using it can be a little hard at the beginning... You can even preview your design on your smartphone or watch.

You should definitely take a look at this !

Comment: i would love to use pixate, i ithink it is exactly what i need...but the problem is it is not running on Ubuntu/Linux. Trying to start it with wine didn work as well

Comment: Hum sorry, I didn't know that...

Comment: That's very interesting to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used [FluidUI](http://fluidui.com) for prototyping my application. Check it, as far as I rememeber, free account allows you to have only one project there, but it was enough in my case.